# Eclipse pomx.xml: Conflicting lifecycle mapping metadata (project packaging type="war")

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, war

I have  follwing problem with war packaging in my pom xml: "Conflicting lifecycle mapping metadata (project packaging type="war"). To enable full functionality, remove the conflicting mapping and run Maven->Update Project Configuration." Even If I update project the problem still occurs. Everything was working good in this pome before I installed hibernate with problems:
[Hibernate installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzcS6.jpg)

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.database</groupId>
  <artifactId>nwind</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Northwind Database</name>
  <description>Aplikacja obslugujaca baze danych Northwind</description>


    <!--Spring library version -->
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--End Spring dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>    
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <finalName>Nwind</finalName>

    </build>
</project>
```

Please tell me what should I do to fix it.